# What are these Pebbles

Tags: geology

Found these Pebbles at a lake edge where a Serpentinite belt runs through, there are lots of serpentine pebbles along this lake in Co. Sligo Ireland.

[image]
[image]
The larger pebble is 1 5/8'' a Yellowish white color underneath and translucent, and has a tiny pitted surface The smaller pebble is opaque.

Comment: Hi. When I fixed your image links, I noticed that  the third picture was the same as the first, so I removed that one. The surfaces of course are due to rounding during transportation.

Answer (score 3):

The white one is milky quartz, the yellowish/brownish one could be some variation of quartz or quartzite, too.

[Further information about quartz and milky quartz can be found here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartz#Milky_quartz)